# React build won't load an image file

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

What happens is that the image loads correctly on my dev build, but once I've made a prod build, it doesn't load the correct file path. I've removed the unnecessary codes and files to make it simpler.

Here is the file tree:

```
src
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┗ media
 ┃ ┃ ┣ images
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ success.svg
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┣ payment-success.page.jsx
 ┗ _app.js
```

_app.js

```
import PaymentSuccess from "./payment-success.page"
...
  <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    //Here is the link to where my image is
    <Route exact path="/payment/success" component={PaymentSuccess} />
  </Switch>
```

payment-success.jsx

```
import Success from "../assets/media/images/success.svg"
...
const PaymentSuccess = () => <div> <img src={Success} /> </div>
```

The image loads on the dev build properly, but on the prod build, what happens is that it loads as src="./static/..." resulting in the image loading at

```
url.com/payment/static/media/images/success.svg
```

instead of

```
url.com/static/media/images/success.svg
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, no. What I did as a work around was change the directory from /payment/success to /payment-success.